# bower.json and .bowerrc missing from ASP .NET MVC template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, bower

While the Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code MVC templates comes with some client packages such as jQuery, jQueryValidation, bootstrap etc. the bower.json and .bowerrc files are completely missing, so when I go into the VS bower package manager I don't see the already installed packages which is quite annoying.

The thing is this started happening to me 2 weeks ago( around the time I tried npm package manager and did a VS Code update), how can I re-enable bower appearing with the MVC template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be related to bower being deprecated.  Those libraries in the template are no longer managed by bower thus they don't show in the manager.  If you manually add the bower.json and .bowerrrc files you might be able to continue using bower for js library dependency management.  First delete the local copies of the js files that were not added by bower, then re-add them using bower.

However, bower [recommends](https://bower.io/blog/) using yarn for js library dependency management.  For the client packages jquery, jquery-validation, and bootstrap you could use yarn, npm, or local copies.  But for large common libraries like jquery you may want to include from Google's CDN https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery